# Why for loop never ends?

Tags: c, arrays, string, for-loop, variable-length-array

```
int ln;
printf("how many letters are your name?\n");
scanf("%d", &ln);
printf("Ok...enter your name by characters: \n");
char name[ln];
for (int i = 0; i<=ln; i++){
    scanf("%s", &name[i]);
}
```

This code should transform a name in the array but the for-loop never ends. Someone who can help me?

Comment: Format specifier, VLA,... standard library already has functions to read a string.

Comment: Note: `%s` is for reading **strings**.

Comment: use `getchar()` to read characters ... or, if you must (but really you shouldn't) ... `scanf(" %c", ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*Why for loop never ends?*"

First things first, I do not think that the loop is infinite. For me it seems that you are just confusing `%s` with `%c` and interpret the waiting for more input as loop that "never ends".

You didn´t provided sufficient ressources to rebuild your issue, though.

But let´s get started:

1. The `%s` conversion specifier of `scanf()` is for reading a string, not a single character. If you want to read a single character per iteration, use `scanf("%c", &name[i]);` or `name[i] = getchar();` instead of `scanf("%s", &name[i]);` in the `for` loop.
2. Your loop condition `i <= ln` is faulty, as you attempt to write one character more than expected with it, because index counting starts at `0`, not `1`. Use `i < ln` instead.
3. A string needs to have a terminating null character at the end. `name` needs to have one element more than to just hold the letters of the input name. Also place `name[ln] = '\0';` after the loop to insert a null character in the last element of VLA `name`.

---

#### Note:

If you want to read a variable amount of characters from `stdin` which is determined at run-time, you don´t need to read each character separate and stop until the counter reaches `ln - 1`.

Reading a  string with a variable amount of characters is one point, where `fgets()` is more appropriate than `scanf()`.

Use `fgets (name, sizeof(name), stdin);` which ensures that the read string plus the string-terminating null character will fit  exactly into `name` and catch the name once.

```
int ln;

printf("How many letters are in your name?\n");
scanf("%d", &ln);
getchar();              // catching left newline from scanf.

char name[ln + 1];      // +1 for null character.

printf("Ok...enter your name: \n");

fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);   // Will read the name and append the null character.

getchar();              // catching left newline from fgets.
```

Comment: I've tried this code but when I run it, it stops after 2 characters

Comment: @Jack_01 Hmm... :-/ I need to see your corrected code, I guess.

Comment: @Jack_01 Is `Ok...enter your name by characters:` printed?

Comment: ```int ln;
printf("How many letters are in your name?\n");
scanf("%d", &ln);
getchar();           
char name[ln + 1];     
printf("Ok...enter your name by characters: \n");
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);  
getchar();   ```

Comment: @Jack_01 Okay. What is your actual input and when do you press Enter?

Comment: length of name or the characters?

Comment: @Jack_01 Do you press Enter after each character? I think I missed to say that you should not do that.

Comment: ah ok, thank you, I'll try to put one time the name

Comment: @Jack_01 Did not changed the printing Intention. Deleted `"by characters"`. My fault. I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

%s is scanning string so technically your whole name is considered as one element. So have to enter many strings . just replace %s by %c and code should be ready to use

Answer (score 0):

> Why for loop never ends?

Inside the loop, `scanf("%s", &name[i]);` attempts to read a name `ln + 1` times, eventually attempting to save data outside `name[]` bounds.

Saving data outside `name[]` bounds is *undefined behavior* (UB).  Anything may happen.

---

Loop not needed to read one line of input as a name and `name[]` too small.

```
//char name[ln];
//for (int i = 0; i<=ln; i++){
//   scanf("%s", &name[i]);
//}

char name[ln+1];  // One more for a \0
if (scanf("%s", &name[i]) ==1) {
  Success();
}
```

---

Recommend to not use `scanf()` and use `fgets()`.

```
char name[ln+1+1]; / One more for a \n and 1 for a \0
if (fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin)) {
  name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';  // lop off potential \n
  Success();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the for condition, try to remove that equality and see, because you are allocating ln bytes in name variable, so the variable i will start from 0 and go to ln-1

```
for (int i = 0; i<ln; i++){
       scanf("%c", &name[i]);
   }
```

also note im using %c here to scan character, %s scans string.

Answer (score 0):

Because your for loop must run one more time to end . simply change

```
i<=ln
```

to

```
i<ln
```